# Minimum position vector is important why?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

Let $f(t)$ be a parametrized curve which does not pass through the origin. If $f(t_o)$
is the point of the trace of $f$ closest to the origin and $f'(t_o) \neq 0$, show that the position vector $f(t_o)$ is orthogonal to $f'(t_o)$.

I'm sure I proved the general case that $f(t)$ is orthogonal to $f'(t)$ for all $t$. So why is $f(t_o)$ important? I proved the general case using dot products and some basic manipulations.

Comment: Why would it have to be important?

Comment: thats my question

Comment: also, i did not post my proof since I don't know how to LaTeX yet

Comment: Here's how it's done: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference -- to help you start, I have formatted the math you had already written in the question.

Comment: Maybe the real question is where you went wrong in your "proof" of the general case. But nobody can answer that question without having seen the "proof".

Comment: Let $f(t) = < x , y >$. We know that the unit normal vector is orthogonal to the tangent vector. Let $u$ denote the unit normal vector for f(t). $$u = f(t)/|f(t)| = < {x \over x^2+y^2}, {y \over x^2+y^2} >$$. Since $u$ is orthogonal to $f'(t)$ thus $${u}\cdot{f'} = 0 = {xx'+yy' /over x^2+y^2} = 0$$. Multiply both sides by $x^2 + y^2$. Thus you get $xx'+yy' = 0$ which is equivalent to ${f}\cdot{f'}$. Thus f is orthogonal to f'.

Comment: i think i might have confused the definition of unit normal vector... yeah thats probably why.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had already written most of an answer when I saw that you had also noticed the same error. If you want to answer your own question and accept that answer, you can do so; if you do, mention it in a comment on my answer and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason $f(t_0)$ is important is that your "proof" of the general case is wrong.

Given the vector $f(t)$, then $\frac{f(t)}{\|f(t)\|}$ is a unit vector
pointing from the origin toward the point on the curve corresponding to $f(t)$.
This is not generally equal to the unit normal vector of the curve.

Moreover,
$$\frac{f(t)}{\|f(t)\|} 
= \left\langle\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right\rangle,$$
so your formula for $\frac{f(t)}{\|f(t)\|}$ was mistaken; but that doesn't
really matter, since that was not the vector to use in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure of a false statement. Consider a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through $(0,1)$, parallel to the real axis. $f(t)$ is clearly not orthogonal to $f'(t)$ for all $t$.

What you want is to use that $0=\frac{d}{dt}\langle f(t), f(t) \rangle|_{t_0}=2\langle f(t_0), f'(t_0) \rangle$